# AWS IAM CLI tag-user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

good morning. Does anyone have any advice for tagging a user with the AWS CLI? I am following the AWS documentation found here for adding tags to a user:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/tag-user.html
The example they provide is:

```
aws iam tag-user --user-name alice --tags '{"Key": "Department", "Value": "Accounting"}'
```

This is the command I am running for my purposes:

```
aws iam tag-user --user-name access-Arnav-peg-eng --tags '{"Key": "access-project", "Value": "peg"}'
```

When I run the command, however, I receive the following error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--tags': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
'{Key:
^
```

I have tried a number of different permutations and combinations figuring maybe the CLI has changed but the documentation hasn't been updated, but none of those worked.

Some examples included:

```
aws iam tag-user --user-name access-Arnav-peg-eng --tags "{"Key"="access-control","Value"="peg"}"

aws iam tag-user --user-name access-Arnav-peg-eng --tags '[{"Key"="access-control","Value"="peg"}]'
```

And so on. Have I been typing something wrong? Has the CLI changed and the documentation doesn't reflect that? Each time I try to add a tag to a user from the command line, it doesn't work. I know everything is properly configured. I have been creating users and performing other actions from it. I am using aws-cli/2.2.44 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided example does not work on Windows. See [Using quotation marks with strings in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html), specifically the `Windows command prompt` tab.

Try:

```
aws iam tag-user ^
    --user-name alice ^
    --tags "{\"Key\": \"Department\", \"Value\": \"Accounting\"}"
```

Note that I made my example multi-line for clarity (via the caret at the end of each partial line), but you can remove the carets and joins the lines together, if you prefer, like so:

```
aws iam tag-user --user-name alice --tags "{\"Key\": \"Department\", \"Value\": \"Accounting\"}"
```

The key thing is that the Windows command prompt requires double quotation marks `"..."` to enclose the JSON data structure, so you have to escape any embedded double quotes like so: `\"`

Comment: That worked perfectly, first try. Thank you very much. I didn't realize the docs were meant for something other than Windows, maybe I missed that. But writing it out just like you showed worked great in the Windows command prompt.  Again, much appreciated. Also, the advice on escaping the quotes was helpful too.